# Data cleansing from un-normal-to normalised tables migration

Tags: database, ms-access, migration, microsoft-dynamics

I'm cleansing data for a client. We're migrating from a legacy helpdesk MS Access system to a Customer Relationship management package, MS Dynamics 2015.

The llgacy system's invoice table is VERY un-normal. It has everything in one table Name of client, ticket number, description of helpdesk query and so on. This

creates a scenario where John Smith logs a helpdesk ticket, one instance of John Smith, with a phone number (808-234-123) is created each time a helpdesk ticket is

raised (and one row is written to the TICKET table). JOhn Smith has logged hundreds of tickets and has been entered in the database as

```
Name        Phone number
John Smith  (808-234-123)
J. SMith    (808-234-123)
John S.     808234123
Johnny Smith    ????unknown
Jonathan Smith  234-123
```

and so on.

What I'd like to do is
1. agree with the business what the definitive spelling of John Smith and his actual phone number
2. run some sort of cleansing routine\package\whatever to update the close-to-definitive John Smiths into the definitive John Smith

This is necessary because the Dynamics CRM uses a far more normalised database and we want 1 John Smith with n records, not n John Smith with n records.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **Analyze** tool in Access

> Database Tools, and then in the Analyze group, click Analyze Table

https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Normalize-your-data-using-the-Table-Analyzer-8edbb763-5bab-4fbc-b62d-c17b1a40bbe2